# Styled-component, using theme variables in Render

Tags: reactjs, themes, styled-components

I know that we can use theme variables like this:

```
const Button = styled.button`    
   cursor: pointer;
   border-radius: ${props => props.theme.borderRadiusSize};
   dir: ${props => props.theme.dir}
   outline: none;               
`;
```

Above is working. I need to do something more than changing styles, with some of theme variables.
eg:

```
if (theme.dir === 'rtl')
   do some stuff more in render!
```

I tried to use `theme` object from `props` like this:

```
const {theme} = this.props;
if (theme.dir === 'rtl')
   do some stuff more in render!
```

But the `theme` props is undefined.

Can I use the `theme` object passed from the parent `<ThemeProvider/>`? I don't want to use a global state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. [Here](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#getting-the-theme-without-styled-components) is the documents.

Previously I was doing like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';


class Component extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const {
      theme
    } = this.props;

    console.log('Current theme: ', theme); // Gets undefined

    ...

    return (
      ...
    )
  }

}

export default Component;
```

I changed to this:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled, {withTheme} from 'styled-components';


class Component extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const {
      theme
    } = this.props;

    console.log('Current theme: ', theme);  // Gets theme object

    ...

    return (
      ...
    )
  }
}

export default withTheme(Component);
```

Comment: I misunderstood your initial question. Good find (Y)

Answer (score 0):

It does not look liked styled-components gives you an easy way to access the theme.  It seems like you maybe want to use React `context` or some other global config if that's what it truly is.  Accessing the theme from the ThemeProvider for something other than styles would be accessing the internals of styled-components.

Comment: I tried to access internal of `styled-components` but could not find any useful object.

Comment: Right, as did I.  There doesn't seem to be a public or easy to find private API to do this.  That is why I suggested a different solution.  If you think about it differently, it might work better.  Currently, it seems like you are asking a CSS styling rule to inform non-CSS logic, positioning, etc.  The other way around, if you try keeping a more general variable in context/global state,  _it_ can influence styling rules as well as everything else.  `context.direction` could decide font direction, as well as logo placement, etc.